# Can I obtain a visa for Brazil at a land crossing?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, borders, visas-on-arrival, brazil

The standard Brazil visa application seems to be quite a long and involved process which requires plenty of documentation. I have heard a long time ago though that one can instead get the visa at a land crossing and that this is much faster.

**Is it still possible to get a Brazil visa at a land-crossing?** If so, what is needed for a Canadian for documentation and how long does the process take?

Would it be possible for this to be a multiple entry visa and for how long?

Which border towns offers this?

One in Uruguay or Paraguay would interest me in particular.

Comment: Ten countries border Brazil, including Argentina, Bolivia, Colombia, French Guiana, Guyana, Paraguay, Peru, Suriname, Uruguay and Venezuela - are you wanting to restrict your question to just Paraguay and Uruguay?

Comment: Those would interest me more since I have not been there before, bu also French Guyana, Guyana and Suriname but I would also like the land crossing to be accessible. I suppose in some of those places, it's right in the middle of the jungle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I could not find a way, so I indeed applied for a Brazilian visa and flew in, as flights in and out of Brazil are a requirement to obtain the visa.

Still, to put this question to rest, I finally dug out the information which was not that hard to find once I took a few lessons in Brazilian Portugese. The [official site of the Brazil government](http://www.portalconsular.itamaraty.gov.br/vistos-para-viajar-ao-brasil) even includes a snippet in English answering exactly this question:

> Take note that the Brazilian visa will never be granted in Brazilian
>   territory. Therefore, it is not possible to obtain your visa in
>   airports, ports of entry or any other point of the Brazilian border.

It might have been different a while ago but this is the information published as of today January 10, 2017.